# Error with clicking button using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to scrape this [URL](https://www.wayfair.com/brand/bbb/browse-by-brand) and trying to navigate the next Brand list on the website. I use selenium click by.XPATH and got the error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`,

this is the code I executed

```
for i in soup.find_all('div', class_='ShopBrandsAlphabetically-brandLink'):
    title = i.find('a', href = True)
    results.append(title.text.strip())
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//button[@name='0-9']")). click()
```

and this is the webpage element

```
<button name="0-9" value="0-9" type="button" data-hb-id="Button" class="_1vl5e1z1_713 _1vl5e1z2_713 _1vl5e1z6_713 _1vl5e1z9_713 _1vl5e1z11_713"><span class="_1vl5e1zd_713 _1vl5e1z12_713 _1vl5e1z16_713 _1vl5e1z18_713"><span class="ShopBrandsAlphabetically-filter"><p data-hb-id="Text" class="j3rpje110_713 nhya890_713" style="--j3rpje10w_713:inherit">0-9</p></span></span></button>
```

can anyone tell me where's my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `By.XPATH` wrongly.

The call should be this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@name='0-9']")
```

But instead you did this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//button[@name='0-9']"))
```

The parentheses immediately following `By.XPATH(...)` indicate that you're treating it as a function.  But it is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to put a comma between `By.XPATH` and `"//button[@name='0-9']"`.

Because you are putting `By.XPATH("//button[@name='0-9']")` inside the type parameter, selenium thinks you are tying to click `By.XPATH("//button[@name='0-9']")`, which is a string and not the button you are attempting to access.

In conclusion, try using this:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@name='0-9']").click()
```

This should get the button you are tying to access.

Answer (score 0):

As per the defination [`find_element()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element) finds an element given a [`By`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.by.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.by) strategy and a locator and is defined as:

```
def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value: Optional[str] = None) -> WebElement:
    """Find an element given a By strategy and locator.

    :Usage:
        ::

            element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'foo')

    :rtype: WebElement
    """
```

---

### Solution

In your usecase instead of `function` you need to pass as a [***tuple***](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tuples-in-python/) as follows:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@name='0-9']").click()
```

---

However the desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element, so to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[name='0-9'][value='0-9'] p"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@name='0-9' and @value='0-9']//p[text()='0-9']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```